# Questions about Cartan Lie Algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

I have a subalgebra $B = b(n,F)$ of L.

$b(n,F)$ is the subalgebra consisting of all upper triangular matrices. Then $b(n,F)$ is clear NOT a cartan subalgebra since it is not nilpotent.

But I think that the relation $N_L(B)=B$  still holds...

Can someone please help me to show this? Or to tell me I am not correct in my assertion.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Borel subalgebra $B$ of a semisimple Lie algebra $L$ is self-normalizing (the letter $B$ stands for *Borel* subalgebra), because it is a maximal solvable subalgebra. The proof goes as follows: 
If $x \in L$ normalizes $B$, we may create $B + Fx$, which is certainly a subalgebra of $L$. Here $F$ is the field.
Clearly
$[B + Fx,B + Fx] ⊂ B$, so $B + Fx$ is solvable. Now B is Borel (maximal solvable) so that $x$ must be an element of $B$. Hence we obtain $N_L(B)=B$. Clearly $B$ is not nilpotent, but solvable.

In your example, where $B=\mathfrak{b}_n(\mathbb{C})$, the Lie algebra $L$ is $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$, and its Cartan subalgebra $H$ consists of the diagonal matrices of trace zero, so it is abelian.

Comment: Thank you sir. this method really makes sense. But i still have a little confusion please help me. So the idea of the approach is to notice borel is radical and then construct a subalg of B which contains the element in normalizer. then we can deduce x in normalizer will also be in B. However, why we have [B＋Fx, B＋Fx] is contained in B? thanks!

Comment: And why the this relation give us B＋Fx is in B? i assume B＋Fx is solvable because it is in B? thank you

Comment: Ok, now I think [B＋Fx,B＋Fx] ＝[B,B]＋F[B,x]＋F[x,B]＋F[x,x] which is clearly in B...is this a correct expansion? if so i think i just solved my first question. Could you help me to understand why B＋Fx is solvable? thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Also, $B$ is solvable, and if $[C,C]\subset B$ is solvable, then $C$ is solvable.

Comment: Great I see! Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it!